# How to make voice recognition keep steady when traveling?

Tags: languages, voice-recognition, localization

My Android 10 phone's voice recognition for English works extremely well, but when I travel to India it switches to expect an Indian accent, and I can barely get it to take my dictation that way, even though I can adapt to speak the local accent some of the time.

Can we tweak some settings to avoid this change in the underlying machine learning model so that it keeps interpreting my English dictation as either UK or US accents of English, thus retaining its existing, pre-travel, levels of accuracy?

I really rely on voice dictation quite a lot.

When referring to voice recognition, I primarily mean the voice typing feature available through the Google Keyboard's microphone icon, but I suspect that the same underlying components also handle the "Hello Google" stuff.

When I go outside of India, it clearly does revert back to expecting US or UK accents again, as if over-adapting to the geography rather than remaining loyal to the user that's already using it.

Actually, at least one person native to India who speaks the Indian accent and dialect of English has mentioned the same issue to me, which they only experience in reverse ― voice recognition accuracy plummets for them when they travel to other English-speaking countries.